# Haskell how to generate this infinite list?

Tags: list, haskell, infinite, cyclic

I saw this code to generate Fibonacci numbers.

`fibs = 1:1:(zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs))`

Can a similar styled code be written to generate the infinite list [1..]?

I saw this [link on cyclic structures](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) on the Haskell website.

There an example is given

```
cyclic = let x = 0 : y
         y = 1 : x
     in  x
```

I tried to define a list for my problem in a cyclic manner, but could not succeed.
What I want is a list defined in terms of itself and which evaluates to [1..] in Haskell.

Note: The Haskell `[1..]` evaluates to `[1,2,3,4,5...]` and not to `[1,1,1...]`.

Comment: This one is not the same as `[1..]` in Haskell. The Haskell `[1..]` evaluates to `[1,2,3,4,5...]` while your one evaluates to `[1,1,1,1...]`.

Comment: Ah, ok. `nats = 1 : map (+1) nats` then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following should give you the desired result:

```
nats = 1 : map (+1) nats
```

Or, more idiomatically:

```
nats = iterate (+1) 1
```

It's easy to see why the first snippet evaluates to `[1,2,3...]` by using equational reasoning:

```
nats = 1 : map (+1) nats 
     = 1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) nats) 
     = 1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) nats))
     = 1 : 1 + 1 : 1 + 1 + 1 : .... 
     = [1,2,3...]
```

Comment: `nats = iterate succ 1` gives an even better intuition for what happens, in my opinion. Applying the successor function over and over will naturally yield the set of naturals.

Comment: @kqr: If you start at zero, that is!

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

Think about how you could write out each element of your list:

```
1
1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

After each entry, every subsequent entry has an extra `+ 1`. So we want to start at `1` and then add `1` to each subsequent element. Then we want to take the second element and add `1` to everything after that.

Here's how we can do this:

```
let xs = 1 : map (+ 1) xs
```

This expands like this:

```
1 : map (+ 1) xs
1 : (1 + 1) : map (+ 1) xs
1 : (1 + 1) : ((1 + 1) + 1) : map (+ 1) xs
```

and so on.

Comment: how can you append the list, without knowing what list actually is? I mean, after : sign everything should be evaluated in order to append the list.

Comment: That's basically how it works :). This can be a tricky idea, so I wrote a blog post about it a while ago with some illustrations: https://jelv.is/blog/Lazy-Dynamic-Programming/

Comment: I've asked my teacher today and he said that it is not evaluated. It is evaluated when we call `take` or other function. But `print` somehow can evaluate it, without actually evaluate the end

Answer (score 0):

Actually, because Haskell's laziness is *call by need*, having defined

```
xs = 1 : map (+1) xs
```

then calling e.g. *`print xs`* proceeds as

```
xs
xs  where  xs = 1 : map (+ 1) xs
xs  where  xs = x1 : xs2 ; x1 = 1 ; xs2 = map (+ 1) xs
x1 : xs2  where  xs2 = map (+ 1) (x1 : xs2) ; x1 = 1
x1 : xs2  where  xs2 = (x1+1) : map (+ 1) xs2 ; x1 = 1
x1 : xs2  where  xs2 = x2 : xs3 ; x2 = x1+1 ; xs3 = map (+ 1) xs2 ; x1 = 1
1 : x2 : xs3  where  xs3 = map (+ 1) (x2 : xs3) ; x2 = 2
1 : x2 : xs3  where  xs3 = (x2+1) : map (+ 1) xs3 ; x2 = 2
1 : 2 : x3 : xs4  where  xs4 = map (+ 1) (x3 : xs4) ; x3 = 3
1 : 2 : 3 : x4 : xs5  where  xs5 = map (+ 1) (x4 : xs5) ; x4 = 4
.....
```

so that there's no repeated computations of `n+1` by repeated additions of `1`s. The `n` is already computed.

We just give a name to every place, so that the name holds  a computation to be performed, at first, and then its value, afterwards. Since the name is shared among other computations, there's no repeated calculations of its value.

Same thing happens with the calculation of the Fibonacci numbers list.

---

So then `xs` indeed generates the list `[1,2..]`. The process of repeated additions of `1` is naturally expressed as `iterate (+1) 1`, as already noted in another answer.

We could also define this as

```
nums1 = xs where
        ys = 1 : ys
        xs = zipWith (+) (0 : xs) ys
```

which is perhaps what you were trying to express.

The definition of a list by zipping with itself shifted by one step (as in the Fibonacci list definition) gives the mapping function access to two previous elements of the list simultaneously while defining the current element.

Similarly, the definition of a list by zipping itself shifted by one step and another list (as with the definition of `nums1` above) gives the mapping function access to the *previous* element while defining a current one.

We say "mapping function" because `zipWith` is a binary `map`:

```
zipWith f xs ys = map (\(x,y) -> f x y) (zip xs ys)
```